# CSS positioning of text over image

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to fiddle around with Html and css and want to position text over an image. I have managed to do this on my homepage and figured I'd use the same class and the text would be positioned correctly aswell.
The homepage looks like this: [Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRNt4.png)
The html code looks like this:

```
<div class="textoverimage">
     <img src="./imgs/Restaurant.jpg" alt="me">
     <div class="textforoverimage"><h2>Second year IT student</h2></div>
 </div>`
```

The css looks like this:

```
.textoverimage img{
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 277px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
.textforoverimage h2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 18%;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-size:60px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  }
```

The about me page, in which I want to achieve the same effect of text over image, **but only on the second image** looks like this: [About page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y07rM.png)

The html code looks like this:

`<div class="textoverimage">
  <img src="./imgs/Restaurant.jpg" alt="Restaurant">
  <div class="textforoverimage"><h2>Jobs & Schooling</h2></div>
 </div>`

As you can see, the Jobs and schooling text is shown at the top of the page. I thought that because textforoverimage was positioned absolute it would be moved according to the position of its parent, which I thought was the textoverimage div. However it seems to be positioned according to the page.

What am I doing wrong? Am I using the position property wrong or is it a html mistake?

Comment: You'll get much better responses if you post your code into a code snippet so others can recreate the issue you're seeing.  Especially with CSS it's hard to help without the context of all the CSS/HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `position: relative` to `.textoverimage` , not to the image - that's the parent element which needs to function as an anchor for the absolute position of its child element. And apply `position:absolute` to `.textforoverimage` , not to the `h2` which it contains.